Normalizing voltage circuit
Given input voltages \$\{ V_{x 1}, V_{x 2}, \ldots, V_{xn} \}\$, we want to
obtain output voltages \$\{ V_{y 1}, V_{y 2}, \ldots, V_{yn} \}\$ such that:

Each output voltage \$V_{yi}\$ is proportional to its corresponding
input voltage \$V_{xi}\$.

The sum of all output voltages equals \$V_{\mathrm{DD}}\$: \$\sum_{i = 1}^n
  V_{yi} = V_{\mathrm{DD}}\$.


Is this possible using just passive analog components like resistors, capacitors, and diodes?

It's not very clear what you want. I understand you want a linear network to do that job. Is the input data serial or parallel?

You get a set of input voltages, so parallel.

It doesn't sound easy, because there's scaling needing, by an arbitrary and variable amount, which would require some kind of gain control. Also, consider what happens when $V_{x1}=V_{x2}=...=V_{xn}=0V$, how can you normalise that?

@SimonFitch, the condiiton when all the inputs are 0 does not occur. So, we don't have to worry about that. I have also thought about rewriting the problem such that feedback could be used to solve it, but this requires using opamps. Since I believe there could be a much easier solution, I did not mention that in my post to avoid pushing potential answers towards that direction.

Are all these signals DC? So they are constant and you just want to have a fixed scaling factor to make them all sum to VDD?

@Designalog, that's right.

Are the input voltages strictly smaller than VDD or it doesn't matter?

You should add some details about why you want to do this. The problem as presented looks like an XY problem. Without further context, it could be inferred you are aiming for an audio mixer with constant SPL output. In which case, this would be the wrong approach.

The short answer to your question is, yes it is possible. But horribly impractical in real life and much too complicated to present here. Considerable compromises would have to be made.

@Designalog, yes all voltages are above 0 and less than VDD.

If by "basic components" you mean "passive components", then no, this is probably not possible. If you allow active components (at least transistors, preferably op amps or even all the way to microcontrollers), this is definitely doable. Trivial with a microcontroller and sufficiently many ADCs and DACs.

@Hearth, it's obviously trivial on a microcontroller. It's two lines of code.

@LeonhardEuler Yes, that's my point. You need to clarify what you mean by "basic components". I'd assume a microcontroller doesn't count as basic, else you wouldn't have asked this. But does an op amp?

@Hearth, I think you're just being pedantic here. I already gave examples like resistors, capacitors, and diodes. Surely, this and the fact that the problem is so trivial on anything that runs code, it is easy to assume that microcontrollers are out of the question.

@LeonhardEuler As I said, it's probably not possible with just resistors, capacitors, and diodes. I'm trying to determine what the limit of what you consider "basic" is, because you need more than your examples alone.

@Hearth, I've modified my question. Anything passive is fine.
